# How to link to the existing project in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Eclipse has a good feature that I can link to other project in the same workspace as a dependency specified in pom.xml.  Is it possible for me to do the same in intellij ?

Answer (score 0):

Of-course you can do, I am doing a sbt project having dependencies of multiple projects. It will be easy to debug if you attach the dependent projects. It can be achieved easily by holding the `ctrl` and mouse clicking on any of the methods from the other projects in your current project. It will open the compiled code of the same. Then to the right top corner you can find `Choose Sources...` . Click that and in the explorer go to your dependency project and select the source. There you can see other project in the same workspace.

Comment: I change the version of the dependecy to 0.15-SNAPSHOT which is another project in intellij, but intellij could not find it. How can make intellij find it automatically like eclipse ?

Comment: It will not find by its own, you got to choose the source of that another project. But it will help in simplifying your search like, in the Attach Sources popup left top you got intellij icon, click on that to land in the source directory of your project. You just need to select that other project from there.

Comment: I don't want to link it on the source code level, actually I want to build with the latest code in the other project. Is there anyway to do that ?